# Simple refactoring

Tags: php, refactoring

How can I refactor this code so I have only 1 line for assigning $filename value.

```
$i = 1;
$filename = $config->PHOTO_PATH . $list->ID . "_" . $i . ".jpg"
while(file_exists($filename)) 
{
    doSomething();
    $i++;
    $filename = $config->PHOTO_PATH . $list->ID . "_" . $i . ".jpg";
}
```

Comment: If you want a clear answer, specify what this is supposed to do. I guess you're trying to find an untaken filename, but what does `doSomething()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 1;

$ok=true;
while($ok) 
{
    $filename = $config->PHOTO_PATH . $list->ID . "_" . $i++ . ".jpg";
    $ok=file_exists($filename)
    if ($ok){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = 'prefix' .
            (preg_replace('/prefix([0-9]+)suffix/', '$1', array_pop(glob('prefix*suffix'))) + 1) .
            'suffix';
```

Comment: Interesting solution, though quite obscure. Is `glob` guaranteed to return sorted results? Also note that this doesn't `doSomething()`; I don't know how important that really is.

Comment: @deceze `glob` return sorted result, but in this code you cannot insert `doSomething()` because it require a `while` if it must called every check, and in a line you cannot insert a while.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your following code:

```
$i++;
$filename = $config->PHOTO_PATH . $list->ID . "_" . $i . ".jpg";
```

for this one:

```
$filename = $config->PHOTO_PATH . $list->ID . "_" . ++$i . ".jpg";
```

Comment: Should probably use pre-increment operator.

Comment: Yes  I confused them, now fixed, thaks for spotting it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
do {
    doSomething();
    $filename = sprintf('%s%s_%d.jpg', $config->PHOTO_PATH, $list->ID, $i++);
} while (file_exists($filename));
```

Comment: Maybe doSomething() is supposed to do something with the filename which it doesn't know if it exists yet or what the name of it is

Comment: @baloo Unless that's more clearly specified, we won't know that.

Comment: Hello. doSomething() indeed needs to know the filename. Sorry that I didn't make that clear

Comment: @Roger Well then, generating the filename first, *then* calling `doSomething` should do it.

Comment: Not really, because you don't know if that file exists before calling doSomething()